# Git status print only directory level information

Tags: git

After some additions/removals in my local git repo, when I type `git status`, I get thousands of files affected:

```
deleted:  node_modules/...
deleted:  ......
......
```

Right now, in order to get only the directories affected, I run the following on my bash:

```sh
git status | grep  -oE \[^\/\]\* | sort | uniq
```

And I get a clean (i.e. minimal dir level) output as:

```sh
    deleted:    node_modules
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
Changes to be committed:
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin
```

Not that it's a common scenario I run into, but would be good to know if `git` offers something out of the box to get this functionality i.e. directory level info only. I know of `git status --short` but that doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Note you'd typically exclude `node_modules/` from your repo.

Comment: I know- but it was a colleague's creation and actually that's how I ran into this use case :)

Comment: Git doesn't "think about" directories at all, so I doubt that's available.

Answer (score 0):

That would force git status to read *all* files of a folder in order to see if said files:

- are all versioned
- are all impacted by the same operation (deleted)
- are complete (meaning there are not other private files in that same folder which are involved in that mass deletion)

That would not scale well.

In your case, you can simply commit and add `node_modules/` to your `.gitignore`